# Deploying multicontainer docker environment (flask & nginx) with EBS

Tags: docker, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

The following code works when running locally with docker-compose.  However, when I push Flask and nginx containers to ECS and try to launch this application from Elastic Beanstalk, referencing the containers in my Dockerrun.aws.json file as shown below, I am unable to launch my application without error.  Does anyone know how the Dockerrun.aws.json file is to be formatted?  Or, does the problem lie elsewhere?  Thanks!

**nginx/default.conf**:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /usr/src/app/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

**nginx/Dockerfile**:

```
FROM nginx

RUN mv /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.old
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**web/app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**web/Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.5-onbuild

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev
RUN pip3 install flask
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "UsrSrcAppStatic",
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/usr/src/app/static"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "WwwStatic",
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/www/static"
            }
        }
    ],
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "web",
            "image": "############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app_web",
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 4096,
            "command": [
                "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn",
                "-w",
                "2",
                "-b",
                ":8000",
                "app:app"
            ],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/usr/src/app/static",
                    "sourceVolume": "UsrSrcAppStatic"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "nginx",
            "image": "############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app_nginx",
            "essential": true,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "containerPort": 80
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                "web"
            ],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "WwwStatic",
                    "containerPath": "/www/static"
                }
            ],
            "memory": 128,
            "volumesFrom": [
                {
                    "sourceContainer": "web"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also followed the nginx/php multicontainer [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html) AWS has posted without issue.

Comment: did you solve this? I'm able to run my stack using ECS and a self managed cluster but would like to port this to EBS. They don't support orchestrating the containers with `docker-compose` yet so I need to do what you describe, i.e. "translating" my compose setup into their json format.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but it would be greatly helpful for others if the original poster would provide a followup stating what happened. e.g I got this resolved by doing XYZ or I gave up and moved on to ABC or ... whatever.

Also the original poster provided no details with regards to the error they were getting.

For the benefit of others running on to this post I can see at least one issue  the person may have been experiencing.  When referencing the flask app "web" container from nginx container you can use this "http://web:8000" but with Amazon containers you have to instead use "http://localhost:8000".

Answer (score 0):

Web container is missing property `portMappings`

```
"portMappings": [
    {
        "hostPort": 8080,
        "containerPort": 8080
     }
]
```